# how to repeat each row n times in pandas so that it looks like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how to repeat each row n times in pandas in this fashion

I want this below result(With `df_repeat = pd.concat([df]*2, ignore_index=False)` I can't get expected result ):

Original Dataset:

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 5 | x |

Dataframe I want:

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | x |
| 0 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 5 | x |
| 5 | x |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the index:

```
df_repeat = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
```

output:

```
   index value
0      0     x
0      0     x
1      1     x
1      1     x
2      2     x
2      2     x
3      3     x
3      3     x
4      4     x
4      4     x
5      5     x
5      5     x
```

For a clean, new index:

```
df_repeat = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
    index value
0       0     x
1       0     x
2       1     x
3       1     x
4       2     x
5       2     x
6       3     x
7       3     x
8       4     x
9       4     x
10      5     x
11      5     x
```

##### on Series

Should you have a Series as input, there is a [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) method:

```
# create a Series from the above DataFrame
s = df.set_index('index')['value']

s.repeat(2)
```

output:

```
index
0    x
0    x
1    x
1    x
2    x
2    x
3    x
3    x
4    x
4    x
5    x
5    x
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Wouldn't df.repeat(2) itself suffice here?

Comment: @Zero there is no `repeat` method for DataFrames to my knowledge (it exists for Series and Index)

Comment: The dataframe they have shared only has a single column `value` so I guess that `repeat` works on single-column dataframes

Comment: @Zero the number of columns does not matter, a single column DataFrame is still a DataFrame and has no `repeat` method. If you have a Series (which does **not** seems to be the case here), yes, `repeat(2)` should work. I'll add a note